# VBA copy certain columns from one sheet to another when condition is met

Tags: excel, vba

New member here trying to fathom what might be wrong with the following code...

I am trying to copy rows from "A5" to the last row and columns A:L except columns "C & D" when C = "Y" but not getting anything when execute Macro and debug now giving much away (although I am new to this :-)). Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub UpdateImportFile_Click()

Dim count As Long
count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A5", Range("A5").End(xlDown)))

For i = 5 To count

If Worksheets("Case Entry").Cells(i, 3).Value = "Y" Then

    Worksheets("Case Entry").Rows(i).Columns(1, 2).Copy
    Worksheets("Import File").Activate
    Worksheets("Import File").Cells("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End If

Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Case Entry").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate I only included columns 1 & 2 in the worksheet copy - should be columns 1,2,5,6,7,8,9,10,11

Comment: If you debug your code (You can step through using F8) what value does `count` get assigned?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub UpdateImportFile_Click()

    Dim count As Long
    count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A5", Range("A5").End(xlDown)))

    With Worksheets("Case Entry")
        For i = 5 To count + 4
            If .Cells(i, 3).Value = "Y" Then
                Worksheets("Import File").Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value = .Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, 2).Value
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```